# How do you incorporate a variable in a NSLayoutConstraint string?

Tags: autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, swift2

Is there a correct way to use a variable within a constraint string as demoed below?

```
let x = 6
self.addConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "H:|-x-[subView(==16)]|",
    options:[], metrics:nil,
    views:viewDictionary))

self.addConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "V:|-x-[subView(==16)]|",
    options:[], metrics:nil,
    views:viewDictionary))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the `metrics` dictionary is for. Pass a dictionary like `[ "x": x ]`.